# Generating Flex like graphics server side

Tags: apache-flex, server-side-scripting

I know flex is a client side technology, but our customers are asking us to e-mail them reports (i.e. graphic images) that look just like the flex graphics we show them on the desktop on a nightly basis.  Is there some server side technology that could help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a AIR app from the command line, write the report to disk and then have another process send the report as an email to the customer.

Its been done and it works.

Comment: can you please provide sample example, i am also having same scenario and need to write a Air application.But i am new to that technology

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always produce the graphics on your dev server, take a screenshot and e-mail them...can't you?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give them secure web access to the Flex project instead?

Its been done and it interactivly works. I belive Flex is all about interaction.